# error docker: invalid reference format. when execute docker run

Tags: shell, docker, nginx, command-line

Complete command is

`docker run --name mynginx2 -v /var/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \ -v /var/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx:ro -P -d nginx`

Why its not working?

I found it here https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`\` is breaking up the command

Run the whole thing without the '\'

`docker run --name mynginx2 -v /var/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -v /var/nginx
/conf:/etc/nginx:ro -P -d nginx`